# What weapons are effective against Pips in DeathSpank?

Tags: deathspank

What weapons are effective against Pips in the burned town in DeathSpank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, a good weapon to use against the "Pip enemies" is one of the fire variety. Physical weapons do almost no damage.